# How to Use Link in website with JSOUP?

Tags: java, jsoup

I have a problem.
I'm using JSOUP, but I came across a link that has the following code:

```
<A href = "javascript: void (0)" onclick = "goTo (1921, 'previous'); Title = "Previous">
...
</a>
```

What parameters should I use to trigger this link?

Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't do it directly. This is a href wich on click triggers the execution of a Javascript function (`goto()`) in the browser. You might try to analyze the Javascript code for that function to find out what it does and see if you can get the url to call from that code.